# Sublime Text 3 "wrap selection with tag" and HTML autocomplete do not work properly

Tags: autocomplete, tags, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I try to select a piece of text and wrap it with `<strong>` tag.

After I highlight some text and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (same as using Edit > Tag > Wrap Selection with Tag) my text is surrounded by `<p>` and `</p>`. I then start to type the word `strong` which replaces both `p`'s simultaneously. If I complete typing the word it's ok, but if I use auto completion and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after I've typed `st` for example I get something like:
`<strong></strong>>word</st>`

Tested it with/without Emmet plugin and does the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an `emmet` alternative shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

It asks you for a wrap abbreviation in the bottom of the frame, so just insert `strong` and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will just wrap all the content highlighted.

Comment: Is this still of actuality I didn't not manage to make it work neither did I found about it on the web

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Solution without emmet :

Go to `Packages/User` Add a folder `Snippets`

Creat in it a file named : `wrapstrong.sublime-snippet` which contain :

```
<snippet>
    <!-- $SELECTION peut être appelé plusieurs fois -->
    <content><![CDATA[<strong>$SELECTION</strong>]]></content>
    <!-- Facultatif: Description affichée dans le menu -->
    <description>Wrap in strong</description>
</snippet>
```

And finally bind it to a Key in Key Binding User ->

```
{"keys": [ "super+b" ], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/User/Snippets/wrapstrong.sublime-snippet"} }
```

Relaunch Sublime Text and there you are !